# Use PHP Blob Value from MySQL Database as background image for simple website

Tags: php, html, css, base64, background-image

i'm trying to use an image that I've stored in base64 in my MySQL Database as a background image for my website.

The basic idea is that I have a search function that let's me search for a character/database entry and once the search has found the corresponding entry, it will display an image of this character as the background for the page.

What would be the best way to go about this? I'm using PHP to access the database.

```
echo  '<br> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row[4].'"/>  <br>';
echo  '<br> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$row[5].'"/>  <br>';
```

I use this function to simply display an avatar of the character and their corresponding big art, however I can't seem to get it working as a background, this is what the style for my page looks like:

```
<style>
body {
  background-image: src('<?php echo $row[5];?>');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  }
</style>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd expect you need to include the `data:image/jpeg;base64` prefix in the CSS src as well.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add the base64 context there;

```
.background {
    background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN......");
}
```

in your case:

```
body{
    background-image: src("<?php echo 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $row[5];?>");
}
```